# Keyboard Issues Garage Band

Tags: keyboard, garageband

Alright so I've been working in Garageband for about a month and have made a few tracks, but I've just come across a problem that I have yet to encounter, and I can't find anything about it online. When I was playing on the keyboard, I accidentally hit some keys, I'm not sure which ones, wherein lies the problem, but it made the whole keyboard turn to a faded grey and then I was unable to play on it anymore. I can still see it but I can do nothing. I opened and closed the program but the keyboard is still like that. It seems to me that I just need to hit something to fix it, but I have no idea what that is. There is nothing in product support about it or anything in forums. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Liz...so we are talking about the build in keyboard external one? Which one did you use.

Comment: Did you accidentally lock the track? Try hitting `L` Here is a shortcut list for Garage Band '11 http://support.apple.com/kb/PH1811

Answer (score 1):

Also. If the keyboard is not faded. It might just be that you have the velocity turned down to zero. turn it up :). the velocity controls are right below the keys when you have the keyboard on musical typing mode